# How to fix problem with multi-repo solution in Visual Studio 2022 Community

Tags: c++, git, visual-studio

I have the following structure of my test solution:

```
    TestApp (solution)  
    ├─ TestApp (project)    
    ├─ Submodules  
           ├─ TestLib (solution)   
                 ├─ TestLib (project)  
                       ├─ 3rd_party  
                       |      ├─ include  
                       |            ├─ nlohmann  
                       ├─ pch.h  
                       ├─ TString.h  
                       ├─ TargetEntity.h
```

The `nlohmann` is the JSON library. `TestLib` is a static lib, it included inside `TestApp` as a reference. `TestLib` is a git submodule inside `TestApp` repo. `TestApp` also has the following paths in `Additional include directories`:

```
    $(SolutionDir)Submodules\TestLib\TestLib\3rd_party\include;
    $(SolutionDir)Submodules\TestLib\;
    %(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)
```

Here are the complete code:
**TestApp**
`main.cpp`:

```
#include "TestLib/TargetEntity.h"
#include "TestLib/TString.h"
//#include "nlohmann/json.hpp"

int main()
{
    //nlohmann::json json;
    //json["abc"] = 765;
    TargetEntity te;
    TString      ts;
}
```

**TestLib**
`pch.h`:

```
    #ifndef PCH_H
    #define PCH_H
    
    #define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
    #include "TString.h"
    //#include "nlohmann/json.hpp"
    
    #endif // PCH_H
```

`pch.cpp`:

```
#include "pch.h"
```

`TString.h`:

```
    #pragma once
    
    #include <string>
    
    using TString = std::wstring;
```

`TargetEntity.h`:

```
    #pragma once
    
    //#include "TString.h" // Uncomment to get rid of error
    //#include "nlohmann/json.hpp" // Uncomment to get rid of error
    
    class TargetEntity
    {
    public:
        virtual ~TargetEntity() = default;
    
        //void InitializeFromJson(const nlohmann::json& json) {}
    
    protected:
        TString url;
    };
```

`TargetEntity.cpp`:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "TargetEntity.h"
```

`TestLib` compiles fine as separate solution and when compiled as project inside `TestApp` (I mean, when you compile only the lib). But when I try to compile `TestApp` VS show errors inside `TargetEntity`:

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: TestLib, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>pch.cpp
1>TargetEntity.cpp
1>TestLib.vcxproj -> ...\Temp\TestApp\Build-TestLib-x64-Debug\TestLib.lib
2>------ Build started: Project: TestApp, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
2>TestApp.cpp
2>...\Temp\TestApp\Submodules\TestLib\TestLib\TargetEntity.h(13,13): error C3646: 'url': unknown override specifier
2>...\Temp\TestApp\Submodules\TestLib\TestLib\TargetEntity.h(13,16): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
2>Done building project "TestApp.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
```

So, it seems VS somehow ignores precompiled header for `TestLib` during compilation of `TestApp`. I know, `multi-repo` is a preview feature, but my scenario seems "obvious" to me, may be someone knows how to solve this problem.

I've noticed that including corresponding headers inside `TargetEntity` solves the problem, but I don't want to do it in the whole library.

**UPDATE:** I added full code and full build output. For simplicity I also commented nlohmann-related code - problem persists.

Comment: You're not including `pch.h` anywhere?

Comment: Precompiled header included everywhere in .cpp-files.

Comment: That's not shown in your post, please show a [mre]

Comment: What's in `TestApp.cpp`? If that's `main.cpp` then you're not including `TString` before `TargetEntity` so `TString` is undefined in `TargetEntity`. Headers should be self contained and include any other headers that they need so that include order doesn't matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pch.h is missing in your main.cpp. And `#include pch.h` before header files.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "TestLib/TargetEntity.h"
#include "TestLib/TString.h"
//#include "nlohmann/json.hpp"

int main()
{
    //nlohmann::json json;
    //json["abc"] = 765;
    TargetEntity te;
    TString      ts;
}
```